# Optimizing MySQL and Doctrine for Efficient Deletion of Large Data Sets in Symfony Application

Tags: mysql, docker, doctrine

In a Symfony+Doctrine application handling approximately 200,000 records stored in a MySQL database, the goal is to delete outdated data. The data structure consists of the following components:

- `Entry`: The primary record.
- Each `Entry` can have multiple relations to `EntryMeta`.
- The number of related `EntryMeta` records for an `Entry` can be around 50.

When an `Entry` becomes outdated, it needs to be deleted, along with its associated `EntryMeta` records.

To achieve this, the following PHP code is used (after selecting the outdated records):

```php
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if (false === $dryRun) {
        foreach ($entry->getEntryMetas() as $meta) {
            $this->importHelper->getEntityManager()->remove($meta);
        }

        $this->importHelper->getEntityManager()->remove($entry);
    }

    $countDeleted++;
}

$this->importHelper->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

The `flush()` method is called outside the `foreach` block because it's important to handle this operation as a transaction. This ensures that no data is deleted if an error occurs during the process, especially when dealing with other related records.

In this application, it's necessary to delete approximately 99% of the current data stock, and the total count of entries in the data stock can exceed 200k entries (plus relations to `EntryMeta`).

However, when attempting to delete more than approximately 100,000 entries using this approach, the MySQL server sometimes reports a "gone away" error. The MySQL server is hosted within a Docker container, and it currently doesn't have any specific configuration.

Is there any potential for optimization on the MySQL side or within Doctrine to address this issue?

Comment: May be simpler to use foreign keys with cascading delete and just delete the entries from your code with a single sql statement. For such massive database operations I would not use ORM as ORMs are not particularly efficient solutions.